# Boto method for Amazon MWS GetLowestPricedOffersForSKU

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-mws

Boto provides access to most Amazon MWS APIs, but not for GetLowestPricedOffersForSKU. I tried to hack one, but it generates an `Invalid MarketplaceId` error.

Boto has code for a very similarly structured API -- GetLowestOfferListingsForSKU:

```
@requires(['MarketplaceId', 'SellerSKUList'])
@structured_lists('SellerSKUList.SellerSKU')
@api_action('Products', 20, 5, 'GetLowestOfferListingsForSKU')
def get_lowest_offer_listings_for_sku(self, request, response, **kw):
    """Returns the lowest price offer listings for a specific
       product by item condition and SellerSKUs.
    """
    return self._post_request(request, kw, response)
```

So I modified the `@api_action` to change the MWS Operation to GetLowestPricedOffersForSKU:

```
### MINE ###
@requires(['MarketplaceId', 'SellerSKUList'])
@structured_lists('SellerSKUList.SellerSKU')
@api_action('Products', 20, 5, 'GetLowestPricedOffersForSKU')
def get_lowest_priced_offers_for_sku(self, request, response, **kw):
    return self._post_request(request, kw, response)
```

I call this method as follows:

```
conn = connection.MWSConnection(
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
    Merchant=ACCOUNT_ID
)
response = conn.get_lowest_priced_offers_for_sku(
    MarketplaceId=marketplace_id, SellerSKUList=sku_list, ItemCondition=condition
)
```

When I call `get_lowest_priced_offers_for_sku`, I get an `Invalid MarketplaceId` error. If the only change I make is to call `get_lowest_offer_listings_for_sku` -- leaving every variable identical -- the code works find and return a valid response object. This works just fine:

```
response = conn.get_lowest_offer_listings_for_sku(
    MarketplaceId=marketplace_id, SellerSKUList=sku_list, ItemCondition=condition
)
```

What do I need to do to access the Amazon MWS GetLowestPricedOffersForSKU via boto?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure and neither I am python programmer, but In PHP AmazonMWS API I use code below where I use setMarketplaceId()

```
$request = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetLowestPricedOffersForSKURequest();
$request->setSellerId($this->seller_id);
$request->setMarketplaceId($this->marketplace_id);
$request->setItemCondition("New");
```

Answer (score 0):

Boto2 doesnt support `GetLowestPricedOffersForSKU` as you can see from the documentation http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/mws.html